# How to disable auto-copy to clipboard when highlighting text in Gnome (linux)?

Tags: linux, clipboard, gnome

I am trying to find where this functionality is located, so that I can disable it, but can't seem to find it in my Scientific Linux distro (v 6.6).

Based on help I found, I have tried to look for the following packages but none of them is installed.
- xsel
- parcellite
- clipit
- xclip

I have also tried to locate this functionality via the gnome-control-center but was also unsuccessful.

Comment: Take a look into your clipboard application, not sure what Gnome uses for that. Typically you will find some option there like "sync selection and clipboard" or similar.

Comment: @arkascha I can't figure out where my clipboard is, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score -2):

You can't disable it as it is a base feature from X11.

Nevertheless, it's not that bad, since on Linux, you have two differents clipboard :

1. select and middle mouse click (or shift+insert to paste)
2. ctrl+c and ctrl+v (or ctrl+maj+c and ctrl+maj+v in a terminal).

Comment: It's actually the same clipboard that gets overwritten, isn't it? My workflow involves highlighting to copy in the clipboard, then highlighting somewhere to delete and ctrl+v to paste what I had copied. This is of course overwritten by the second highlighting so I essentially end up pasting what I has just deleted. I would like to be able to keep what I ctrl+c in the clipboard until I redo that action.

Comment: No, theses are two **differents** clipboards. If you copy something with CTRL+C and then highlight something, you still have what you copied in CTRL+V clipboard.

Comment: That is not the behaviour I'm seeing. I take then that I have a non-standard X11 response. How could I further investigate this? What system options can I have a look at? Thx.

Comment: if I select anything I'll get this exact selection when doing CTRL+V or SHIFT+Insert